# mysql query using inner joins and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

These are the tables:

```
professor:
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
|     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
|     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
|     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
|     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
|     7 | George |      0 |   1500 |   46 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
works:
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
|        2 |     3 |      10 |
|        2 |     1 |       7 |
+----------+-------+---------+

course:
+----------+------------+--------+
| courseid | coursename | points |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | Maths      |    100 |
|        2 | Science    |     80 |
|        3 | English    |     85 |
|        4 | Social     |     90 |
|        5 | Malayalam  |     99 |
|        6 | Arts       |     40 |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

The question is :

> Return list of employees who have taught course Maths or Science but
>   not both

The query which I wrote is :

```
select distinct professor.name from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.courseid in
(select courseid from course where coursename ='Maths' or coursename='Science');
```

The output I received is:

```
Arun
Benoy
Chacko
```

Here the employee 'Arun' shouldnt have been displayed as he as taught both Maths and Science.

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an aggregate `COUNT()` to check that the total number of `DISTINCT` courses taught is exactly 1, while still filtering to the two different types of courses.  That ensures that only one, never both, is returned.

Because the `IN ()` limits all rows initially returned only to the two desired courses, professors can have a maximum of 2 possible different courses via `COUNT(DISTINCT coursename)`.  A `HAVING` clause then prohibits those with 2 from the final result set.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT professor.name
FROM
  professor
  INNER JOIN works ON professor.empid = works.empid
  /* Join against course to get the course names */
  INNER JOIN course ON works.courseid = course.courseid
WHERE
  /* Restrict only to Maths, Science */
  course.coursename IN ('Maths', 'Science')
GROUP BY professor.name
/* Only those with exactly one type of course */
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT course.coursename) = 1
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e9610/2

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an `xor` here instead of an `or`.

```
select distinct professor.name from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.courseid in
(select courseid from course where coursename ='Maths' xor coursename='Science');
```